# ¿Como evitar el bloqueo del archivo al que cargue en PictureBox usando Image.FromFile?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Quiero cargar una imagen pero cuando intento remplazar el archivo me devuelve que el archivo esta siendo usado. Como puedo evitar que tome directamente el archivo, dejándome la posibilidad de poder remplazarlo.

Uso:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\images\out.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de usar `Image.FromFile`, puedes usar `Image.FromStream` y le pasas los bytes del archivo usando `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Ejemplo:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\images\out.png")))
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono al problema que tenía hace días.

Answer (score 0):

**NO se puede**, esto es una restricción agregada por el sistema de lectura del framework, le recomiendo si desea usar/modificar el archivo crear una copia temporal, modificarlo y visualizarlo. De lo contrario nunca podrá hacer las dos cosas al tiempo.

Comment: ¿Me daría un ejemplo de como crearía esa copia temporal y asignarla en la picturebox?

Comment: System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination");
En source colocas la ruta "D:\images\out.png"
En destination : "D:\images\nueva.png"
y luego usas:
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\images\nueva.png")

Answer (score -1):

A mi me funcionó la siguiente treta:

```
picturebox.image=new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(ruta));
```

Me dio la solución al mismo problema.